# Match 2 data frames if at least 3 keywords are matching

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, keyword-search

I have 2 dataframes, df1, df2.

df1 contains fake news stories

*`story = [[1, 'sun rotates around earth'],[2,'coffee is harmful for health, it causes cancer. It helps noone']]`*

*`df1 = pd.DataFrame(story, columns = ['story_no', 'story'])`*

df2 contains OCR texts extracted from posts

*`ocrdata = [[1234, 'sun, earth and everything in the Milky Way galaxy rotating around a black hole'],[3456,'I love coffee'],[5678,'coffee helps preventing cancer and keep us healthy']]`*

*`df2 =  pd.DataFrame(story, columns = ['postid', 'OCR_text'])`*

***I want to match df1 with df2 if at least 3 keywords are matching between `df1['story']` and `df2['OCR_text']`***

> **in above example for first row 'sun', 'earth', 'rorate' keywords(atleast 3 keywords) are matching so it would be a match, in second row only 'coffee' is matching(less than 3 keywords) hence it won't be a match, but in 3rd row of df2 4 keywords (greater than 3 keywords) are matching('coffee', 'health', 'cancer', 'help') hence it would be a match**

***I want output as***

***`Columns: [story_no, story, postid, OCR_text, matching_keywords]`***

> So the sample output for above dataframes would be

| story_no | story | postid | OCR_text | matching_keywords |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'sun rotates around earth' | 1234 | 'sun, earth and everything in the Milky Way galaxy rotating around a black hole' | 'sun', 'earth', 'rorate' |
| 2 | 'coffee is harmful for health, it causes cancer. It helps noone' | 5678 | 'coffee helps preventing cancer and keep us healthy' | 'coffee', 'health', 'cancer', 'help' |

> I have created a function which return keyword list

```py
def get_keywords1(row):
    some_text = row
    lowered = some_text.lower()
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(some_text)
    keywords = [keyword for keyword in tokens if keyword.isalpha() and not keyword in stop_words]
    keyword_list = [w.replace(' ', '_') for w in keywords]
    return str(''.join([''+ ''.join(sent) + '. ' for sent in keywords]))
```

But I am not able to match both the dataframes as per above requirement. I am new into python and pandas, any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this is a tricky and potentially computationally expensive match to perform, please provide a better example with more rows to demonstrate how you would need this to generalize

Comment: @mozway I updated my question with added example, could you please help if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. But I think you should do three methods. One for first dataframe and one for the second dataframe to prepare the data to be matched. and another method for matching both the dataframes. the third method should take 2 arguments (story,ocr_text) and should return the matching keywords.